# How to explain behaviour of function agrument handling?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function:

```
def test_func(a, b):
    print a
    print b
```

I know it's not right to use a dictionary when function call looks like this:

```
a = {1:2, 3:4}
test_func(*a) # function expects a sequence as an argument
```

It should be a turple or a list instead. But console shows no errors and prints keys of this dictionary: 1 and 3.

Looks like this: when function call expects a sequence, but takes a dictionary, it pulls dictionary's keys as sequence of argument. Is it ok?

Comment: `Is it ok?` - Yes your observation is correct and it is perfectly okay.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can also do `for key in D`.

Comment: to unpack a dictionary as named arguments you use `**`.

Comment: It depends. The order in which the keys will be assigned to the arguments is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` *is* a sequence. More specifically, when a `dict` is iterated, the iteration yields the keys of the dictionary (in an unpredictable order).

Consider

```
for i in {1:2, 3:4}:
    print i
```

The result will print 1 and 3, because iteration of a `dict` yields the keys.

As an aside, there is also an interesting way to use dictionaries to pass arguments:

```
a = {'a':2, 'b':4}
test_func(**a)
```

The double-asterisk passes the values of the `dict` to the similarly-named parameters of the function. In this case, the function prints 2 and 4, in that order.

Comment: The result *may* be 1 and 3; it might also be 3 and 1.

Comment: It is true that the order of the output of the first snippet is indeterminate.